# Does it make sense to come to Miami at the beginning of October?

Tags: miami

I have planned a trip to Florida (Orlando-Cape Canaveral-West Palm Beach-national Park-Miami) that includes a stay in Miami on 10.01-10.05. How do you think, does it make sense to spend there 5 days and overall 2 weeks on Florida? I'm from Poland, there's no hurricanes there so I do not know what to expect. Do you think it will be fine till Then or should we change our plans? How is The situation right now there? I would do thankful for any advises!